# How to solve this variable pass into batch_date?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to pass in @batch date into batch_date...But it shows error...The error is

> Column 'dbo.tnx_tid_InvCheck_Details.Batch_Date' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.

The `InvCheck_Details` table has `batch_date` for each and every `part_no`. I want to group the part_no so that I can count(tid) and sum(tid_bal) by part_no. What should i do in order to run this script? TQ...

```
DECLARE @batch_date datetime
SET @batch_date = '2012-10-13 00:00:00.000'



CREATE TABLE #inv_check
(batch_date datetime,part_no varchar(25),Number_of_tid int,Updated_DT int, Tot_Tid_Bal int)

INSERT INTO #inv_check
SELECT batch_date,part_no,COUNT(tid)as Number_of_tid,0,sum(Tid_Bal)
FROM dbo.tnx_tid_InvCheck_Details
where batch_date = @batch_date
Group by part_no
order by part_no

UPDATE #inv_check 
SET Updated_DT = isnull(d.Updated_DT,0) 
--select i.part_no,i.Number_of_tid, isnull(d.Updated_DT,0)
FROM #inv_check i
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT part_no, COUNT(LastUpdate_DT)as Updated_DT,
    sum(tid_bal) as Tid_bal_sum
    FROM dbo.tnx_tid_InvCheck_Details
    Where NOT LastUpdate_DT IS NULL
    Group by part_no) d on i.part_no=d.part_no  



    DECLARE @sql int
    DECLARE @sql1 int


SELECT @sql1 = count(part_no) 
FROM #inv_check

SELECT @sql = count(part_no)
FROM #inv_check
WHERE number_of_tid= Updated_DT

SELECT @sql AS Parts_Counted,@sql1 AS Full_Parts

Drop table #inv_check
```

Comment: The error message is pretty self-explanatory. You either need to include `batch_date` in the `GROUP BY` or you need to decide which row you want (e.g. `MIN(batch_date)` or `MAX(batch_date)`).

Comment: The answer is in the error message. Just remove `batch_date` from the first select list, you don't use it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO #inv_check
Select y.batch_date,x.*
From dbo.tnx_tid_InvCheck_Details y
Join(

    SELECT part_no,COUNT(tid)as Number_of_tid,0 AS Updated_DT,sum(Tid_Bal) As Tot_Tid_Bal
    FROM dbo.tnx_tid_InvCheck_Details
    where batch_date = @batch_date
    Group by part_no
    )x
On x.part_no = y.part_no
order by x.part_no
```

Comment: This will yield a different variation of the same error. You removed the GROUP BY but are still trying to aggregate on *some* of the columns - why?